# Pandas Dataframe.describe() : Which kind of standard deviation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, standard-deviation

Using python's Pandas library, the [Dataframe.describe() function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html#pandas.DataFrame.describe) prints the standard deviation of the dataset. However, the documentation page doesn't specify whether this standard deviation is the ["uncorrected" standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Uncorrected_sample_standard_deviation) or the "corrected" standard deviation.

Can someone tell me which one it returns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the *corrected sample standard deviation*.
You can convince yourself of this with a simple Series and applying the formulae:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([1, 2])

In [12]: s.std()
Out[12]: 0.70710678118654757

In [13]: from math import sqrt
   ....:  sqrt(0.5)
Out[13]: 0.7071067811865476
```

and the formula for corrected sample standard deviation:

```
In [14]: sqrt(1./(len(s)-1) * ((s - s.mean()) ** 2).sum())
Out[14]: 0.7071067811865476
```

Answer (score 4):

`DataFrame.describe()` [calls `Series.std()`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/5ef3cc389086cdc73b14ed1158c3cb6240d99f56/pandas/core/generic.py#L3713) to get the standard deviation. And as [the documentation tells us](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.std.html#pandas.Series.std),

> Return unbiased standard deviation over requested axis.
>
> Normalized by N-1 by default. This can be changed using the ddof argument

So the standard deviation returned by `describe()` is, in fact, the "corrected sample standard deviation".